# After fiddler shutdown my internet stops working

Tags: fiddler

When I shut down fiddler my browser is not able to access any website. When I restart fiddler, its starts working again. After shutting down fiddler I checked proxy settings on ie and made sure it was reverted to "automatically detect proxy settings."

I even restarted the machine and that didn't help. What else can I try?

This problem is reproducible when I press F12 and stop capture of traffic in fiddler.

Comment: Which browser? What exactly do you see in the browser in question? Do you have a 3rd-party firewall program installed? Does your environment require a proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

From command prompt use inetcpl.cpl to launch the internet options, then check in Connections->Lan Settings if the proxy is enable, just disable it by unchecking "Use a server proxy for your LAN"

Answer (score 0):

Late answer in case someone comes across this issue. I installed Fiddler Everywhere and unless I was connected to my VPN, my internet would not work at all. The problem was the proxy settings that were modified that didn't go away after uninstalling.

It's a simple fix:

1. Start Menu
2. Open Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy Settings
3. Under "Manual proxy set up" disable "Use a proxy server" or anything that Fiddler may have entered down here

After that, you should be good to go.