# Chrome:The website uses HSTS. Network errors...this page will probably work later

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

I am developing against localhost. This morning right after I used fiddler I started getting this error on chrome (works correctly in firefox)

"You cannot visit localhost right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later."
[image]

Now localhost works in chrome only if fiddler is running. I already made sure the proxy redirects that fiddler makes are corrected when fiddler shuts down.

I also tried importing the certificate to my trusted root and restarting the browser (and also the machine).

Comment: I encounter this issue when the IT admin change their policies. Everything I need to do is to run the command: gpupdate /force

Comment: On the same page, just type on your keyboard THISISUNSAFE. even though you think you are not typing. anywhere just typing together.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

One very quick way around this is, when you're viewing the "Your connection is not private" screen:

<s>type `badidea`</s>

type `thisisunsafe` (credit to [The Java Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3217039/the-java-guy) for finding the new passphrase)

That will allow the security exception when Chrome is otherwise not allowing the exception to be set via clickthrough, e.g. for this HSTS case.

This is only recommended for local connections and local-network virtual machines, obviously, but it has the advantage of working for VMs being used for development (e.g. on port-forwarded local connections) and not just direct localhost connections.

*Note: the Chrome developers have changed this passphrase in the past, and may do so again. If `badidea` ceases to work, please leave a note here if you learn the new passphrase. I'll try to do the same.*

*<s>Edit: as of 30 Jan 2018 this passphrase appears to no longer work.</s>*

<s>*If I can hunt down a new one I'll post it here. In the meantime I'm going to take the time to set up a self-signed certificate using the method outlined in this stackoverflow post:*</s>

*<s>[How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596)</s>*

*<s>Edit: as of 1 Mar 2018 and Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 this passphrase works again for HSTS-related blocks on .dev sites.</s>*

**Edit: as of 9 Mar 2018 and Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 the `badidea` passphrase no longer works.**

*Edit 2: the trouble with self-signed certificates seems to be that, with security standards tightening across the board these days, they cause their own errors to be thrown (nginx, for example, refuses to load an SSL/TLS cert that includes a self-signed cert in the chain of authority, by default).*

*The solution I'm going with now is to swap out the top-level domain on all my .app and .dev development sites with .test or .localhost. Chrome and Safari will no longer accept insecure connections to standard top-level domains (including .app).*

*The current list of standard top-level domains can be found in this Wikipedia article, including special-use domains:*

[Wikipedia: List of Internet Top Level Domains: Special Use Domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Special-Use_Domains)

*These top-level domains seem to be exempt from the new https-only restrictions:*

- .local
- .localhost
- .test
- (any custom/non-standard top-level domain)

*See the answer and link from **codinghands** to the original question for more information:*

[answer from codinghands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218288/1512790)

Comment: never heard of anything like this but for some reason it works! thanks!

Comment: I can't even believe this works but it does. I'm not sure if I should be happy or pissed off that this isn't documented; I've spent HOURS over the years dealing with this crap on Dev environments.

Comment: Use `thisisunsafe` insread of `badidea`. This has been changed with new version

Comment: it works +1, however chrome should really add an option to still proceed with warnings, instead of just blocking

Comment: Is there a version of `thisisunsafe` that works on Android (which doesn't have the physical keyboard)?
BTW I managed to override this by installing Fiddler root cert on the device.

Comment: Where do you type thisisunsafe?  Do you open a javascript console or something?

Comment: @majorgear good question. You type it while the warning screen itself is showing with the browser window focused. The string you type won't appear anywhere, and it doesn't go in any input field. It's just a trick the Chrome developers built in.

Comment: >Is there a version of `thisisunsafe` that works on Android (which doesn't have the physical keyboard)?

You may try [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard), which could be summoned on demand.

Answer (score 214):

When you visited https://localhost previously at some point it not only visited this over a secure channel (https rather than http), it also told your browser, using a special HTTP header: Strict-Transport-Security (often abbreviated to HSTS), that it should ONLY use https for all future visits.

This is a security feature web servers can use to prevent people being downgraded to http (either intentionally or by some evil party).

However if you then then turn off your https server, and just want to browse http you can't (by design - that's the point of this security feature).

HSTS also does prevents you from accepting and skipping past certificate errors.

To reset this, so HSTS is no longer set for localhost, type the following in your Chrome address bar:

```
chrome://net-internals/#hsts
```

Where you will be able to delete this setting for "localhost".

You might also want to find out what was setting this to avoid this problem in future!

Note that for other sites (e.g. www.google.com) these are "preloaded" into the Chrome code and so cannot be removed. When you query them at chrome://net-internals/#hsts you will see them listed as `static` HSTS entries.

And finally note that Google has started preloading HSTS for the entire .dev domain: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: I'm getting this for gmail.com. I went to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and queried gmail.com, got 
Found: 
static_sts_domain: gmail.com
static_upgrade_mode: STRICT
Tried to delete the domain, but am still having the problem.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me. My issue though is that I changed a website nameserver from wordpress (wordpress hosted) to my server (self hosted) and now getting this and presumably so will all the Chrome visitors. Any idea how to get around it for visitors without them deleting their cache?

Comment: Basically only answer is to use HTTPS going forward or hope users don't have it cached. HTTPS is the way forward and free from LetsEncrypt. You should also checked if someone has preloaded your site to browsers code but guess not if you're able to reset it yourself.  Not aware of Wordpress automatically adding HSTS so wonder how that got on there.

Comment: Thanks @BazzaDP - can't see a way around this. I might have to change nameservers back, find out what on the old site was forcing HTTPS then try and migrate again. You can't simply FTP from Wordpress hosted blogs to the new site which is why this is an issue for me and the new site owner doesn't have an SSL certificate (although seriously considering getting one anyway)

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't work? I have a local domain name `mylocal.dev` and when I query "Query HSTS/PKP domain" I find the entry. 
`static_sts_domain: dev`
`static_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS`
Deleting both `mylocal.dev` and only `dev` does not change the entry. I have also tried to delete my browser cache and cookies along with it. Same result.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer preloaded (or static STS) entries cannot be deleted as they exist in the Chrome code and not in a locally maintained list. And as per my last line in my answer, Google have decided to preload the whole dev domain.

Answer (score 70):

Click anywhere in chrome window and type `thisisunsafe` (instead of `badidea` previously) in chrome.

This passphrase may change in future. This is the source

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js#19

According to that line, type `window.atob('dGhpc2lzdW5zYWZl')` to your browser console and it will give you the actual passphrase.

This time the passphrase is **`thisisunsafe`**.

Comment: Its 2021 and typing `thisisunsafe` as described in this post worked for me. Guys its typing not copy and paste!!!!

Comment: it's 2023 and this solution is still working

Answer (score 22):

I had this issue with sites running on XAMPP with private hostnames. Not so private, it turns out! They were all `domain.dev`, which Google has [now registered as a private gTLD](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/03/13/google_developer_gtld_domain_icann/), and is forcing HSTS at the domain level. Changed every virtual host to `.devel` (eugh), restarted Apache and all is now well.

Comment: I can confirm this issue with Opera 50.0.2762.9 and that switching my development domain from `.dev` to `.devel` works around the restriction.

Comment: [RFC 2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) reserves some top level domains specifically to prevent conflicts with private testing. It seems that `.test` is perhaps the most correct one to switch to for development environments.

Comment: This did literally save my life after days of being unable to figure out why chrome was acting like that on my `.dev` localhost domain... God, who'd know...

Comment: Well, actually .test is only recommended for use in testing of current or new DNS related code.

Comment: This here has solved my problem. I'm using Laragon for my development enviroment.

Answer (score 13):

I recently had the same issue while trying to access domains using [CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/).

The only way I found to workaround/avoid HSTS cert exception on Chrome (Windows build) was following the short instructions in https://support.opendns.com/entries/66657664.

**The workaround:**
 Add to Chrome shortcut  the flag `--ignore-certificate-errors`, then reopen it and surf to your website.

Reminder:
 Use it only for development purposes.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try in Google Canary build https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: Suppose you don't have a site that causes a cert error. Then, how would you check if your solution works ? Does not help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902367/making-fiddler-work-with-chrome

Comment: How about mac versions?

Answer (score 7):

I see there are so many useful answers here but still, I come across a handy and useful article out there. https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/

I ran into the same issue and that article helped me to what exactly it is and how to deal with that
HTH :-)

Answer (score 3):

Encountered similar error. resetting chrome://net-internals/#hsts did not work for me. The issue was that my vm's clock was skewed by days. resetting the time did work out to resolve this issue. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4454607?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

This policy mechanism guarantees only secure HTTPS interactions with websites (and never HTTP). The HTTP Strict Transport Security acronym stands for HTTP Strict Transport Security. Keeping the protocol up-to-date prevents attacks on the security protocols like [this one](https://calculerunpourcentage.net).

The vulnerability within HSTS that HSTS responds to was first discovered by a 2009 BlackHat Federal talk titled "New Tricks for Defeating SSL in Practice." Marlinspike's tool, SSLStrip, demonstrates the vulnerability in question.

A secure HTTPS connection is converted back to an unsecured HTTP connection using the tool. The solution is to use HSTS to communicate with the browser that HTTPS connections are always recommended. By using HSTS, cookies will no longer be intercepted by exploits such as Firesheep that steal login credentials through cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter same error, and incognito mode also has same issue.
I resolve this issue by clear Chrome history.

Answer (score 0):

I have been suffering of this issue for very long time. I was unable to open websites like GitHub.
I almost tried all the answer on web and not anyone worked. Tried to reinstall chrome also. 
I found the solution for this from our network guy and it worked.
There is a fix in registry which will resolve this error for permanent basis.

1. Press **Windows+R** key to open run dialogue box
2. type : **regedit**and press enter to open registry
3. In the tree view at left click through following path  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > POLICIES > Microsoft > SystemCertificate > Authroot**
4. Now double click on **DisableRootAutoUpdate** on the right and set it to 0(zero) in the dialogue box appearing
5. Restart your PC to apply registry changes and you will not get this error anymore

The solution above is for Windows 8. It is almost identical in later versions but i’m not sure for earlier versions like XP and vista. So that needs to be checked.

Comment: Do you know what this option means ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 : No sir

Comment: Was suffering from this google-analytics.com along with various other google domains. This answer solved my problem.

Comment: The article at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2813430/an-update-is-available-that-enables-administrators-to-update-trusted-a explains the behavior of the keys that were introduced in a patch for Windows Vista. Setting this particular value to 0 causes updated root certificates to be automatically fetched from Windows Update and installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. In an enterprise environment, this may be turned off as a security measure; however, that means that someone should manage Trusted Root Certification Authorities at the enterprise level.