# Express-subdomain not seeing route

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the example setup from the https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain package. However, when I try api.localhost:3000 in a browser it throws an error: "Cannot GET /"

How can I get api.localhost:3000 running? I would consider other solutions, not just ones using `express-subdomain` as long as you don't have to type in the fqdn in the setup.

app.js:

```
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// *** Code examples below go here! ***
var router = express.Router();

//api specific routes
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});

app.use(subdomain('api', router));
app.listen(3000);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "auth_manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-subdomain": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use this middleware while developing locally, you have to ensure that your subdomain is listed in your hosts file. Refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain#developing-locally).

On MacOS:

1. Adjust host file to forward requests from url:

   `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

   `127.0.0.1       myapp.dev`

   `127.0.0.1       api.myapp.dev`
2. Clear cache:

   `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
3. In express:

   `app.use(subdomain('api', router));`
4. Any authentication middleware needs to be adjusted to authenticate `api.myapp.dev` not `localhost`
5. In Chrome you can use the `api.myapp.dev` url
6. If you are using SSL (https) and have a self signed cert: Chrome usually blocks the hostfile URL if it is not `localhost`. Then, you need to click anywhere in the Chrome window and literally type in `thisisunsafe` and it will let you through. Refer to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268264/chromethe-website-uses-hsts-network-errors-this-page-will-probably-work-late/38881582).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the API is alive at http://api.example.com/ and not in the api.localhost:3000. However if you want to run them locally I suggest that you follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain#developing-locally

Comment: Still having an issue with a host file. It works without the subdomain but not with it.