# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when loading geojson file

Tags: google-chrome, geojson

I'm looking for some help figuring out why this issue occurs and how to fix it. I'm trying to create an interactive map (replicate [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/timeline-animation/)). I have a .geojson file "capecchi.github.io/projects/AirQuality/static_temp.geojson" with all the data, but opening williamcapecchi.com/AirQuality/AQmap_static.html causes the error "net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE" (When using Chrome-- It seems to work fine in IE). I've read other answers related to this error, but being new to development, I'm not sure what is causing this error in my case. After reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355890/neterr-insecure-response-in-chrome) I checked the security tab in developer, but instead of finding an explanation of the certificate problem, only saw this:

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Bill

*edit: apparently I can't add images to questions yet and so I'll explain: when I check the security tab it simply tells me that "This page is not secure." On the left, I see "Main Origin" as http: //williamcapecchi. com and "Non-Secure Origins" as http:// d3js. org. Clicking on either of these it tells me "Your connection with this origin is not secure."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, my solution was to use http:// addresses instead of https://. Then everything worked fine!