# aws: ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE Cloudfront AWS Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm getting a ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE Error if I do a call from my angular app to my backend (beanstalk) and can not figure out what the problem is.

My setup is this:
[image]

My angular app is hosted in a s3 bucket and reachable via https://my-app.mydomain.com. The certificate *.mydomain.com is displayed as valid and everthing is fine. 
Now if I call the login function I get the Error ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE and no additional hint.
The angular app calls a spring application that is hosted in beanstalk.
For cloudfront I had to create a certificate in N.Carolina. I have the same certificate in Frankfurt for my LoadBalancer and Eleastic beanstalk. Could this cause the problem?

Update: The problem must be in beanstalk. If I open my beanstalk url directly (https://myappname.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/heartbeat) it says - that the certificate for *.mydomain.com would not match myappname.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com). How can I assign this? My CNAME is an external service not route53.

Comment: What browser are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355890/neterr-insecure-response-in-chrome

Comment: I'm using Chrome, Safari the same behaviour. Firefox shows invalid certificate on load of my website

Comment: Does FF point to the actual reason that it is invalid?  If you can post a redacted version of the SSL cert report from qualys

Comment: The certificate must be in N. Virginia to use with CloudFront. How you have configured your DNS (pointing to CF or Beanstalk URL)?

Comment: I pointed it to CF. To get my angular app from s3

Comment: I meant north Virginia not Carolina