# Random ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE for content hosted on azurewebsites.net? Works after page refresh?

Tags: azure

I have a hosted website using an Azure webapp. Sometime yesterday, portions of my website began to fail with network requests showing ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.  Random image files, css, sometimes even the index (which Chrome really doesn't like).  **However**, if I refresh a few times in Chrome, the assets load just fine.  I'm access the site through the subdomain created when the webapp was set up so the SSL certificate is for *.azurewebsites.net and appears to be valid.

Is there a way to debug this further?  Logs from my server don't seem to be showing any issues and there isn't a clear repro.

Comment: Possible issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355890/neterr-insecure-response-in-chrome

Comment: Possibly, although I'm able to reproduce the issue in Safari as well.  Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Are you referencing assets from any other websites?

Comment: I am, but the failing assets are coming my azurewebsites.net subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was pretty simple and I wanted to post in case anyone stumbles across this because (I think) the settings by default were in the config that served the error.

I had a custom domain and had set up SSL for that domain on my Azure web app.  The error I was seeing is that from time to time Azure would return the default SSL certificate for azurewebsites.net instead of the SSL cert I had purchased for the domain.  The fix was to switch from IP SSL to SNI SSL.  This can be done from the "SSL Settings" in your Azure Web App. Click the host name and modify the SSL Type.