# Getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when calling url using fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to call a URL which has some SSL settings and after calling it I straight away have to login in order to access the contents  and I get this error while calling it

```
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

my code is

```
  let header = new Headers({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });
let username="***";
let password="***";
let url ="***";
let sentData={
    method:'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    header: header
};
return new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
    fetch(url, sentData)
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(responseText=>{

            console.log(responseText);

        }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Sorry I can't share the URL, username and password. How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355890/neterr-insecure-response-in-chrome

Comment: @Umair i'm able to access it using chrome but with fetch api i'm still getting this error

Comment: Did you tried with different browsers ?

Comment: Yes i did using mozilla

Comment: Ok @Anisha I'll update you, if I have any lead.