# how to fetch data from a site which gives NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

How can I fetch data from a site which gives `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` using fetch API.  I used this but got `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`
Below is my code

```
let header = new Headers({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });
let username="***";
let password="***";
let url ="***";
let sentData={
    method:'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    header: header
};
return new Promise((reslove,reject)=>{
    fetch(url, sentData)
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(responseText=>{

            console.log(responseText);

        }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I can't share the url ,username and pwd.

Comment: Problem with the ssl certificate, if the site is localhost you can try `http` instead of `https` but if you need ssl and the site is yours then use a proper [CA certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE when calling url using fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504887/getting-neterr-insecure-response-when-calling-url-using-fetch-api)

Comment: Nice, a possible duplicate to a question without an answer.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using NPM then you can install Axios and ignore SSL errors like below.

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

But I think you cannot bypass SSL error if you are running Javascript on browser as it will be blocked by Security layer of the Browser. Please have a look into this issue.
[Bypassing SSL certificate error in jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723415/bypassing-ssl-certificate-error-in-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: AFAIK an answer that says "use something else" without giving a reason why it does not work, or even try to find a solution is not a good answer.

Comment: @YanickRochon I already mentioned the reason of why it does not work `if you are running Javascript on browser as it will be blocked by Security layer of the Browser`
why you get this error is either because the server has invalid certificate due to expiry or invalid certificate data. I thought its already a known thing for this issue. The quesiton clearly asks, how to access not why its not accessible.

Comment: thank you for the reply, invalid SSL is not the issue for me. The certificate is self-signed, and the browser can access the site just fine (although it asks for unsafe navigation, which can easily be avoided by adding it to the trusted site). Unfortunately, `fetch` still fails regardless.

Comment: this code won't even run in the browser to have a chance of failing, because there is no such symbol `https`