# Chrome not trusting Fiddler certificates

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, fiddler

Similar to this question:

[Chrome Doesn't Trust Fiddler Root Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195469/chrome-doesnt-trust-fiddler-root-certificate)

But the upvoted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818661/1250301) doesn't seem to be working for me in fiddler v 5.0.

If I load a site with `https` in chrome I get `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` message. If I "reset all certificates" under the HTTPS tab of the options dialog (as per the suggestion in the answer) then I no longer get the certificate errors in Chrome, but Fiddler will only intercept the "Tunnel to" requests and nothing else. If I close fiddler and restart it, then my certificate is no good again for some reason!

Comment: Have you cleared the chrome cache? Websites may pin the used certificate once loaded without Fiddler in between.